# Nav addClass/removeClass on click 

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, nav

I have a menu that links to content on the same page and through jQuery fades div's in and out, working perfectly.

The first link in the navigation has a class attached to it (current_page_item) and I would like, on click of any other link in the navigation, to remove that class and add it to the clicked link.

So far I've tried something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav-links a").click(function(){
        $("#nav-links ul li").removeClass("current_page_item").find("li:last a").addClass("current_page_item");
        });
    });
```

which doesn't work.

I'm very new to javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the HTML for the navigation:

```
            <div id="nav-wrap">

                <ul class="group" id="nav-links">
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#recent" class="linkclass recent">RECENT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work" class="linkclass work">WORK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#who" class="linkclass who">WHO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services" class="linkclass services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="linkclass contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

EDIT 2:

Using the answers below it still doesn't seem to achieve what I want. Perhaps it's because of the jQuery plugin I'm using (magic line). [Link](http://css-tricks.com/5582-jquery-magicline-navigation/)

So basically I'd like the 'line' to stay underneath what is clicked. Which works if I load a new page with the 'current_page_item' in the right place, but as I'm fading DIVs in and out, I can't do that.

The line bounces back to the li item with 'current_page_item' class. Perhaps this code can be modified to add the class to the clicked element?

Here's the code.

```
    $(function() {

        var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
            $mainNav = $("#nav-links");

        $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
        var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

        $magicLine
            .width($(".current_page_item").width())
            .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
            .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
            .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

        $("#nav-links li a").hover(function() {
            $el = $(this);
            leftPos = $el.position().left;
            newWidth = $el.parent().width();
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: leftPos,
                width: newWidth
            });
        }, function() {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: will create a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net), so that we cab easily manipulate and solve your problem.

Comment: We have to see your HTML markup to help you. Can you edit your question and add HTML markup of `#nav-links` section?

Comment: I updated my answer, please also check [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/wgW4L/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach clicked element with `$(this)` and access to it's parent `li` element with `parent()` to add `current_page_item` class. Below is the final code and you can find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/wgW4L/2/).

```
$(function() {
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = $("#nav-links");

    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#nav-links li:not('#magic-line') a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this).parent();
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    },function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    }).click(function() {
         $mainNav.find('li').removeClass('current_page_item');
         $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
         $magicLine
            .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
            .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like it would do what I need but it's still not working. I've added more of what I'm doing in the original post if it helps

Comment: Works perfectly in the fiddle, thank you for that. For some reason on mine the 'magic-line' has stopped moving but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed, was a css issue. Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav-links a").click(function(){
        $("#nav-links li").removeClass("current_page_item").closest("ul").find("li:last a").addClass("current_page_item");
        });
    });
```

.find() only finds decedent elements. you are doing .find on an li which is the sibling of the element you are searching for.

Comment: Seems like it would do what I need but it's still not working. I've added more of what I'm doing in the original post if it helps

Comment: Your #nav-links element is a ul. Your selector had an extra ul in it. I've edited my answer to reflect the fix

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#nav-links a").click(function(){
 var B = $(this);
$("#nav-links ul li").removeClass("current_page_item");
B.addClass("current_page_item");
        });
    });
```

try this

Comment: Also seems like it would do what I need but it's still not working. I've added more of what I'm doing in the original post if it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. `nav-links` is a `ul` so `$("#nav-links ul li")` means all `li`s
   within a `ul` witch is a descendant of `nav-links` and obviously
   there's none. You have to use `$("#nav-links li")`.
2. As everybody else mentioned `.find` searches for all descendents and that's not what you're looking for. Use `.closest("ul")` just before `.find`

Hope it helps.